# what is the default weight initialization method for pytorch geometric Sageconv layer?

Tags: python, graph, pytorch-geometric

What is the default weight initialization method for Pytorch geometric SAGEconv layer?
How to initialize the weights to Xavier for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is KAIMIN
I tried to print out the weights and I found that it is initialised by default with uniform Kaiming, and the weights are in conv1.lin_l.weight and conv1.lin_r.weight. for each SAGEconv layer.